# Blending not working the same on Desire HD and A500 Tab

Tags: android, opengl-es, tablet, libgdx, blending

I'm making a live wallpaper using libgdx as well as gdxlw which is a little framework on top of libgdx for making it easier to make a live wallpaper using OpenGL.

First off, I make sure I'm not using GL20. I wish to try to keep to GL10/GL11 as much as possible. I'm using a simple OrthographicCamera.

What I do each render call:

**1...** Using

`gl11.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);`

`gl11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);`

I fill the screen with white.

**2...** I draw, say, a black square on top, using SpriteBatch and

`batch.setBlendFunction(GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);`

**3...** On top of this I draw a large (usually scaled) image using SpriteBatch and

`batch.setBlendFunction(GL11.GL_DST_COLOR, GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_COLOR);`

Which will then only draw that large image where it's already black and not where it's white. It works as I expected it to and is perfect for my project.

This works perfectly on my HTC Desire HD (Android 2.3.5). However, when I run the very same app on my Acer Iconia A500 tablet (Android 3.2.1) the large image is drawn over both the black and white background without blending.

Regardless of what I've tried to change the blending to when drawing the large image, the result is always the same. The black square is not visible, which it should be. The large image just bulldozes right over it.

**What could I be doing wrong?
Could I be missing something?**

An interesting thing to note is that I tried drawing some random sprites on top of (after) the large image was drawn with various blending which proved that different kinds of blending in fact did seem to work. In other words, blending wasn't completely disabled.

**Do large images behave differently than smaller ones when blending?**

Another interesting thing to note is that when I use Linear filtering on the large image, you can actually make out the black square very faintly. However, it's not visible with Nearest filtering.

Please forgive my confused questions; the only thing in my mind right now is "why does this happen?" and I've been pulling my hair over it all day and tried many approaches with no success.

**Is libgdx not compatible with tablets or Android 3+?** I can't find any reference to that.

**Is [gdxlw](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx-backend-android-livewallpaper/) the culprit?**

EDIT: I've done some tests and found out that if I change the app to use GL20 instead of GL11 I get the same result on my Desire HD as my Acer Iconia A500. That is, I see my large image and extremely (!) vaguely I can see the black behind it.

Also, I'm looking at my **logcat from running a GL11 version on the Acer Iconia A500 tablet**. It states that...

```
02-10 10:58:19.010: D/libEGL(9907): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
02-10 10:58:19.020: D/libEGL(9907): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_tegra.so
02-10 10:58:19.040: I/DEBUG(81): tid 9915 does not exist in pid 9893. ignoring debug request
02-10 10:58:19.040: D/libEGL(9907): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_tegra.so
02-10 10:58:19.040: D/libEGL(9907): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_tegra.so
02-10 10:58:19.050: D/QuickLog(9907): checkGL20 is: true
02-10 10:58:19.080: D/HAL(9907): [HAL] hw_get_module:share library path:/system/lib/hw/gralloc.tegra.so
02-10 10:58:19.290: D/HAL(9907): [HAL] hw_get_module:share library path:/system/lib/hw/gralloc.tegra.so
02-10 10:58:19.290: D/AndroidGraphics(9907): GL20: true
02-10 10:58:19.300: D/AndroidGraphics(9907): OGL renderer: NVIDIA AP
02-10 10:58:19.300: D/AndroidGraphics(9907): OGL vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
02-10 10:58:19.300: D/AndroidGraphics(9907): OGL version: OpenGL ES-CM 1.1
02-10 10:58:19.300: D/AndroidGraphics(9907): OGL extensions: GL_EXT_bgra GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1 GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_NV_texture_npot_2D_mipmap GL_OES_byte_coordinates GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture GL_OES_draw_texture GL_OES_extended_matrix_palette GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_EGL_sync GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap GL_OES_fixed_point GL_OES_framebuffer_object GL_OES_matrix_get GL_OES_matrix_palette GL_OES_point_size_array GL_OES_point_sprite GL_OES_query_matrix GL_OES_read_format GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_OES_single_precision GL_OES_stencil8 GL_OES_texture_cube_map GL_OES_vertex_half_float 
02-10 10:58:19.300: D/AndroidGraphics(9907): framebuffer: (5, 6, 5, 0)
02-10 10:58:19.300: D/AndroidGraphics(9907): depthbuffer: (16)
02-10 10:58:19.300: D/AndroidGraphics(9907): stencilbuffer: (0)
```

...which to me sounds like it's using OpenGL ES 1.1 as intended. I can't find information about what "CM" stands for though. However, looking at my **logcat from my Desire HD** running the same app version:

```
02-10 11:04:16.515: D/AndroidGraphics(10851): GL20: true
02-10 11:04:16.525: D/AndroidGraphics(10851): OGL renderer: Adreno 205
02-10 11:04:16.525: D/AndroidGraphics(10851): OGL vendor: Qualcomm
02-10 11:04:16.525: D/AndroidGraphics(10851): OGL version: OpenGL ES-CM 1.1
02-10 11:04:16.525: D/AndroidGraphics(10851): OGL extensions: GL_AMD_compressed_3DC_texture GL_AMD_compressed_ATC_texture GL_AMD_performance_monitor GL_APPLE_texture_2D_limited_npot GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV GL_OES_blend_equation_separate GL_OES_blend_func_separate GL_OES_blend_subtract GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_draw_texture GL_OES_framebuffer_object GL_OES_matrix_palette GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_point_size_array GL_OES_point_sprite GL_OES_read_format GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_OES_stencil_wrap GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_texture_cube_map GL_OES_texture_env_crossbar GL_OES_texture_float GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear GL_OES_texture_npot GL_OES_texture_mirrored_repeat GL_QCOM_binning_control GL_QCOM_extended_get GL_QCOM_tiled_rendering 
02-10 11:04:16.535: D/AndroidGraphics(10851): framebuffer: (5, 6, 5, 0)
02-10 11:04:16.535: D/AndroidGraphics(10851): depthbuffer: (16)
02-10 11:04:16.535: D/AndroidGraphics(10851): stencilbuffer: (0)
```

...it states that it uses the same OpenGL version as my tablet.

**Shouldn't both implementations work identically if both are the same version?**

**Does hardware, one being Nvidia Tegra and the other Qualcomm, make a difference?**

**Is OpenGL 1.1 "emulated" somehow, and imperfectly so, on a Tegra device?**

I do also see that the list of "OGL Extensions" differs some. For example, searching for anything containing "blend" I find `GL_OES_blend_equation_separate`, `GL_OES_blend_func_separate` and `GL_OES_blend_subtract` on my Desire HD while on my A500 I find none from what I can tell.

**If the problem lies in these extensions, how (if possible) can I solve this?**

EDIT: Ok, so now I got it to work the way I wanted it to but I'm using only GL20. I would still like to solve the problem using GL10 or GL11 if possible, however, as I want more devices to be able to run the app.